# Count unique cell if another cell is not blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to find a way to count the number of unique manufacture who have a product type that isn't blank

```
COLUMN A          COLUMN H
Manufacturer A    Product A
Manufacturer A    Product B
Manufacturer A    
Manufacturer B    Product A
Manufacturer C    Product A
Manufacturer C    
Manufacturer D
```

Based on the above, I know this number would be 3 (Manufacture A has a product - even though they have multiple, Manufacture B has a product, and Manufacturer C has a product; but, Manufacture D does not).

The list I am trying to get work is hundreds of cells long with numerous manufactures and a range of products as options within the table and the columns are not next to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get a fraction of the number by dividing by a COUTNIFS and then add them together with SUMIFS if there is a value in H.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((H2:H8<>"")/(COUNTIFS(A2:A8,A2:A8,H2:H8,"<>")+(H2:H8="")))
```

[image]